# Card View is not appear and also scrollview is not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview, android-cardview

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    .
    .//this card view is showing
    .
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

     <ScrollView>

          <RelativeLayout>


                 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
                  .
                  .//this card view is not showing
                  .
                  </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

                  //data is previewing but not scrolling

                  </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

         </RelativeLayout>


    </ScrollView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

But if I put the second cardview outside of scrollview than it is displaying. I didn't get what is the issue. Thanks a lot if anyone can help.

**Solution I have tried:-**

use of nestedscrollview instead of scroll view.

If question format or style is not matches with Stack Overflow guidelines then let me know, so that in future I will ask questions in better way. Instead of down voting it.

EDIT:

**Complete XML File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/goal_status_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:id="@+id/goal_name"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="Blood Pressure"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/goal_brief"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <customView.timeline_segement
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </customView.timeline_segement>

            <customView.timeline_segement
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </customView.timeline_segement>

            <customView.timeline_segement
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </customView.timeline_segement>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


<ScrollView
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/goal_status_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:id="@+id/goal_card_team"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:text="Your Care Team"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:weightSum="3"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="1.5"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/doctor_photo"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="60dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:id="@+id/doctor_name"
                            android:text="Dr Ankur"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                    </LinearLayout>


                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/applozic_ic_action_add"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="1.6"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/care_manager_photo"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="60dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:id="@+id/care_manager_name"
                            android:text="Cm Ankit"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                    </LinearLayout>



                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_below="@+id/goal_card_team"
            android:id="@+id/action_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </RelativeLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Anyone can help me with this??

Comment: In your start up code fix this `<Relative Layout>` to this `<RelativeLayout>` you have add space between `Relative` and `Layout`.

Comment: that was typo error. I have fixed it. @Ironman.. thanks for pointing it.

Comment: now check it is working or not ??

Comment: Checked not working. @Ironman

Comment: post your full xml code in the question ??

Comment: I have post it. @Ironman

Comment: in your `CardView` you have `2 to 3` `TextView` have `match_parent` height to fix it change it to `wrap_parent`

Comment: Changed the textview height to wrap_content but no luck.

Comment: now tell me which part is not working in your code ..

Comment: Second Cardview  with  android:id="@+id/goal_card_team" is not showing and recylerview with id   android:id="@+id/action_list"is not scrolling.

Comment: The child view of a `ScrollView` should be set to `wrap_content`. If you set it to `match_parent`, it will fill the area of the `ScrollView` and never scroll, because it won't be larger than the `ScrollView`. now change it to `wrap_content`.

Comment: set the child RelativeLayout height to wrap_content but no help. @Ironman

Comment: @Ironman.. waiting for reply.. did you get what went wrong with my code.

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal what's your intended output?

Comment: My second cardview should be show. and it also scroll on scrolling and also my recylerview  item scroll

Comment: right now I am not getting second cardview but recylerview items are showing but they are not scrolling. @VipulAsri

Comment: @Ironman got any hint??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Responding to the own question, if in future anyone get the same problem here is correct answer:-

https://github.com/amardeshbd/android-recycler-view-wrap-content

Use LinearLayout instead of Relative layout and wrap Recyclerview to the relativelayout.